# Linearizing $\, y''+\sin(2x+\cos(2y'+y))+1-\sin(y+3y')=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'd really love your help with the following problem. I need to make linearization and then to find a general solution of the accepted equation for the differential equation:

$$y''+\sin(2x+\cos(2y'+y))+1-\sin(y+3y')=0$$

I usually get a system of two equations, derive them and go on. What should I do in this case? is there a way to turn it into a system of two equation of order one? How it's been done?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest linearization I can think of in this case is to use $\cos(\theta) \approx 1$, and $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$, where $\theta$ is small enough. In your case, these assumptions boil down to making the assumption that $y,y' \approx 0$.

With these assumptions, your differential equation now becomes $$y'' + \sin(2x+1) + 1 - (y+3y') = 0$$ which in turn becomes $$y'' - 3y' - y = - \left(1 + \sin(2x+1) \right)$$
Now you can use your differential equation tricks to solve the above equation to get
$$y(x) = c_1 \exp \left( \left(\dfrac{3-\sqrt{13}}2 \right) x\right) + c_2 \exp \left( \left(\dfrac{3+\sqrt{13}}2 \right) x\right) + \dfrac{5 \sin(2x+1) - 6 \cos(2x+1) + 61}{61}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is there a way to turn this differential equation into a system of two equation of order one?

Comment: Set $z = y'$ to get two equations $$z' - 3z - y = - (1+\sin(2x+1))$$ and $$z=y'$$